# South African ID Number Validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I know this question has been asked previously in this forum. However I have a problem when implementing the code.

I want the system to check if the ID number is a valid South African ID number and get the customer's age, gender and date of birth as well.

**JavaScript file in my view:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        function Validate() {
            // first clear any left over error messages
            $('#error p').remove();

            // store the error div, to save typing
            var error = $('#error');

            var idNumber = $('#idnumber').val();


            // assume everything is correct and if it later turns out not to be, just set this to false
            var correct = true;

            //Ref: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/what-south-african-id-number-made
            // SA ID Number have to be 13 digits, so check the length
            if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {
                error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - input not a valid number</p>');
                correct = false;
            }

            // get first 6 digits as a valid date
            var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));

            var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
            var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
            var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();

            var fullDate = id_date + "-" + (id_month + 1) + "-" + id_year;

            if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4)-1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
                error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - date part not valid</p>');
                correct = false;
            }

            // get the gender
            var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
            var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";

            // get country ID for citzenship
            var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";

            // apply Luhn formula for check-digits
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var checkSum = 0;
            var multiplier = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
                tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
                if (tempTotal > 9) {
                    tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));
                }
                checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
                multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;
            }
            if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {
                error.append('<p>ID number does not appear to be authentic - check digit is not valid</p>');
                correct = false;
            };


            // if no error found, hide the error message
            if (correct) {
                error.css('display', 'none');

                // clear the result div
                $('#result').empty();
                // and put together a result message
                $('#result').append('<p>South African ID Number:   ' + idNumber + '</p><p>Birth Date:   ' + fullDate + '</p><p>Gender:  ' + gender + '</p><p>SA Citizen:  ' + citzenship + '</p>');
            }
                // otherwise, show the error
            else {
                error.css('display', 'block');
            }

            return false;
        }

        function isNumber(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }

        $('#idCheck').submit(Validate);
    });//]]>

    </script>
```

**This is where I want ID number to be entered:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>
            @ViewBag.Error
            @ViewBag.amount@ViewBag.interest@ViewBag.total
        </h4>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.idNumber, "ID Number*")

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.idNumber)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.idNumber, new {@placeholder = "ID Number", style = "width: 200px;", @class = "form-control"})

                        </div>           
                    </div>
```

**This is the code that was suggested for the customer to enter his ID number**

```
    <div id="error"></div>
<form id="idCheck">
    <p>
        Enter the ID Number: <input id="idnumber"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Check"/>
    </p>
</form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

When I try to insert this code out of my `@using(Html.BeginForm())` it works perfectly, however when I put it in place of the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.idNumber, new {@placeholder = "ID Number", style = "width: 200px;", @class = "form-control"})` it doesn't work.

Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "not working"

Comment: @litelite when you enter your ID number in the textbox and click on "Check" the result (that is the gender, age, date of birth, as well as a status that says the ID number is valid) is displayed in labels... what I mean by "not working" is that it doesn't do what I just mentioned, it just reloads the page

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I have tried to put the script tag before `Enter the ID Number: <input id="idnumber"/>` but the validation work your messages are displayed (tested in IE11)